# Fastest way to get rows and data from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I have a search feature on my website where i want to search for users and display the user's first name, last name, and email. what is the fastest way to do that?

My table is:

```
id    first name    last name    email

0     john          bay          johnbay123@gmail.com
1     bob           lof          boblof123@gmail.com
2     bob           mask         mattmask123@gmail.com
```

I have many other rows/users, like 10,000.

For example, the user searches for "bob". what is the fastest way to search the database for "bob" and display each user's first name, last name, and email?

Comment: `where firstname = 'bob'`.  It'll be faster with an index on `firstname`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes thanks but what if the user searched for `lastname`?

Comment: Whatever column is going to be used as a search criteria is a candidate for an index. The more indexes you have the slower an INSERT will be, so that does not mean index everything

Comment: I guess I shouldn't index any columns because the search term can be used to search all columns.

Comment: how does facebook do it? how can you search for anything on facebook that fast?

Comment: Unicorns. They use unicorns.

Comment: simplified presentation of data to table format

Answer (score 0):

You can create a View for the required columns from your Table, you need not include all the columns here.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_yourTable as SELECT *required columns* FROM #YourTable
```

Then you can create indexes on your search columns of your view. This will enable you to search faster using your view, however, it will not impact your INSERT queries on your primary Table.

Comment: A view will not be faster than using the code in the query directly, because that will literally be what mysql does when you use a view in a query. It just shortens your query (in text length, not in query execution time). But you are of course right that indexes should be created.